# Global variable is not changing

Tags: javascript

Im using javascript for getting my current location `(LngLat) ;` and Im using a global variable in order to save the Lng or Lang..

It is changing inside the `function show();` but when finishing its returned back to 1, and `y` is not changing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var y=1;
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show);
} else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}

function show(p) {
y=p.coords.latitude;
//window.alert(y);
x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + p.coords.latitude + 
"<br>Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude; 
}

window.alert(y);//<-- here is the problem , I don't want it to alert 1 !
```

Comment: because the geo location is async, then your alert statement is executed the geo location is not yet completed so `y` value is not updated....

Comment: and how can I fix that? @ArunPJohny

Comment: Fix it by not alerting outside show or other functions. You are not executing anything until you click the button

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but you call the function show once and you never assign p, so you are not giving show an argument.

Comment: but I want to use variable y outside the function @mplungjan

Comment: Y will change value inside the show() function. If you want to see the value change, put the window.alert(y) call inside the show() function.

Comment: You're trying to use the variable before the user clicks on the button that sets the variable. Apart from inventing a time machine it's not possible.

Comment: You can only use the value after it has been set by the callback function show(). You need to chain anything else you want to do with the variable y from inside the show() function.

Comment: @Thealon nope, its working correctly, my problem is just I want to use y containing p.coords.latitude outside show function

Comment: I want a toilet seat made of solid gold, but that is just not in the cards...

Answer (score 0):

See this bit:

```
    function show(p) {
    y=p.coords.latitude;
    //window.alert(y);
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + p.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude; 

    startApp();
    }

    function startApp(){
     window.alert(y);
     // do whatever else you want 
    }
```